# Question about de Rham theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

In Symplectic Invariants and Hamiltonian Dynamics (Helmut Hofer, Eduard Zehnder) P16, they claimed assume M is a connected orientated closed manifold, $\int_M\xi=\int_M \eta$, then $\xi-\eta=d\mu$. How to show this by de Rham theorem? They said nothing but de Rham Theorem, so I do not know which one they mean.

Comment: This post lacks context and is in danger of being closed. Different people may mean different things by 'de Rham's Theorem'. What is the statement you had in mind?

Comment: Also, the words $\textit{orientable}$ and $\textit{connected}$ should be somewhere in your post, given that you mention de Rham's Theorem.

Comment: @Laz You are right, I have edited it.

Comment: @Michael Albanese I do not know which de Rham THM, in my mind, it is said $H^P_{dR}(M)$ is isomorphic to $Hom (H_p(M),\mathbb{R})$. If you could tell me others, I will appreciate for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a consequence of the DeRham isomorphism. In particular, if $M$ is a compact, oriented $n$-dimensional manifold, one proves that we have an isomorphism
$$H^n_{\text{dR}}(M) \cong \Bbb R,$$
with the isomorphism being given by $\displaystyle\int_M$. (Here we're using the fact that $H_n(M,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z$, generated by the fundamental class $[M]$.)

In particular, a form with zero integral represents the zero cohomology class and is therefore exact. (Stokes's Theorem tells you immediately that the integral of an exact form is $0$. This is the converse of that.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind to tell me why $H_n(M, \mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: That’s serious algebraic topology. You can find the DeRham equivalent, for example, in Spivak”s first volume of his five-volume differential geometry text.